# How can I fix this sliding drawer?

Tags: repair, cabinets, drawers

We have a large kitchen drawer - I believe it is known as a metal sided drawer box - used to store pots. The screws have just come undone from the metal side that is attaching it to the front. In order to reattach the screws I need to somehow remove the fixing from the side so I can get into the back of it.

This picture shows the side of the metal side that attaches to the face of the drawer. The arrows point to where the screws need to be fixed to.

[image: Runner]

I imagine that I somehow need to remove this piece. But I cannot for the life of me work out how!

Here is another shot of the side of the metal side if it is of any help :

[image]

Any ideas how I can get to the back of those screw holes?

**Edit** - this hopefully gives a better idea of the components involved :

[image]

**Edit 2** - After a bit of research I have realised my terminology is all wrong. It is the side of a metal sided drawer box that has become unscrewed and not the runner as I was initially saying.

Comment: need pictures of the runner fully extended.

Comment: So the part of the runner that extends is not the piece in the picture.  I may well be using the wrong terms. So the runner attaches to the cabinet and that extends. The part in the picture sits on top of the runner and that fixes to the drawer.

Comment: In the first pic I see two screws which appear to hold the runner cover in place.  I would assume there are two more at the other end.

Comment: @JamesOlson - I believe what you are seeing there are not screws, but rivets. There is no way to remove them non-destructively. Note I have just edited my post, it is not a runner, but the side of the drawer that has become detached. There are 6 of them in total along the one side - but none on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an IKEA MAXIMERA Drawer side. You have to turn the cam nut (circled in red) and either depress or pry away the metal tab to release it (that's why it goes *click*) and then pull out the bracket.

[image]

[image]

([source](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/maximera-drawer-low__AA-1012727-2_pub.pdf))

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I will try as soon as I get home tonight. Interesting to find out where the previous owners bought the kitchen from.

Comment: If you ever need to replace a front, or want to change the look of your entire kitchen, this is how.